# yiiadmin - many-to-many in yii-framework admin interface

Tags: php, yii

I am currently extending yii-s admin extension, yiiadmin.

What would be the easiest way to get a listBox multiple-select field in model-create view, that 
would display many-to-many relation, for example I have a 'pivot' table that holds these 
article-category relationships, along with Article and Category tables.

I already have these relations defined in models, and I even managed to get some other
relations into list view, like Author.name acquired through author_id field in Article table.

Now I want the Article creation
form to contain multiple select listBox that would save into this pivot table automatically 
multiple choices of categories the Article belongs to.

Those would be, therefore, multiple entries/rows into article_category pivot table by one
Article submission.

At the same time, the Article table itself does not contain any field that refers to category.
The pivot table therefore picks up article's id attribute and connects it with categorie's (another model/table)
id and makes a row out of this.

So, for example, I have these tables/models:

Article  >>>  id  | title | author | text

---

Category >>>  id | name | description

---

ArticleCategory >>>  id | article_id | category_id

---

And I want to populate this third pivot table with multiple rows from  multiple select listBox
from the Article create view/form of yiiadmin (often through only one submission).

I also want to automatically render category.name from the Category table into this listbox, appropriately related
to category id-s so that I can show names from category table, and by choice & submission populate pivot table with 
id-s of a category (therefore not names)

Is this possible, and what would be the way to do this?

Comment: have you succeded? interested to see what came out of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this extension to more easily save MANY_MANY relationships:
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/cadvancedarbehavior/
(the gii-template-collection uses this and provides a CRelated widget to create populated Relation form elements for you, it works pretty good I've tried it:
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/gii-template-collection/)

This one claims to do something similar with MANY-to-MANY relationships:
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/save-relations-ar-behavior/

Also, it's fairly easy to write the code yourself. Just populate a CHtml::listBox with the models it's related to, then in the action iterate through them and add the relationships to the 'pivot' table with some simple SQL. Or create a model for the pivot table and you use regular save() AR methods too. You can do this stuff in the afterSave() model event as well, instead of the controller action.

Comment: The first answer I stumbled upon myself, thank you, though. As for the other, I'll look into it as soon as I exaust what I can do with 
CadvArBeh.. Anyway, with CAdvancedArBehaviour it seems like I have to alter names for multiple dropdowns for many-to-many so I can fetch&save them all as one $_POST array (am I missing something? seems every dropdown many-many you add in entry form has different $_POST name? How could I fetch the values & save them if I don't know how many of them and their names - except some cumbersome regex way, which I don't even dare contemplate)

Comment: Anyway, I know I can do it manually, as you suggest, but I'm tryin to find simple ways to automate, since this is a pretty basic task I think I'll probably do again.

One more thing - is there a way to set a layout for all views in a module (not app), so that I dont need to set the $layout variable again and again for all module views?

Comment: If I understand your first comment right, yes, it makes a POST variable of the name of the related model. You may have to hack the extension to change this. Then, if you to that, you can probably override setAttributes to get those POST vars, so it's just one transparent $model->attributes = $_POST['model'] call. That would be pretty slick. Good luck!  
About your second thing: look to the Blog demo for an example of extending CController to add a default $layout. Then just have all of the controllers in your module extend your new Controller with a default layout. Works pretty well. Cheers!